# django rest framework Convert a view to api

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, view

I am a beginner in drf and I need to create this view in drf, but I don't know what method I should use.

```
‍‍‍‍‍‍class CategoryList(ListView):
    template_name = "blog/categorylist.html"
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        global my_category
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        my_category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
        return my_category.articles.published()

    def get_conte‍‍‍‍xt_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = my_category
        return context
‍
```

Comment: That would be a [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)

Answer (score 0):

Using the APIView class is pretty much the same as using a regular View class, as usual, the incoming request is dispatched to an appropriate handler method such as `.get()` or `.post()` [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views)

By overriding the `get` method, you can retrieve the slug from the URL and use it to get the category object.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
# Your other imports

class CategoryListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
        articles = category.articles.published()
        return Response(articles, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And the URL would look something like this

```
path('category/<slug:slug>/', CategoryListAPIView.as_view()),
```